# Selecting and deselecting items individually or together in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I have a matrix of labels, which I add to a GridPane. I have added an event (setOnMouseClicked) to each label in the matrix to select or deselect the same label, so each time I press the mouse, the label of a color (individually) is selected or deselected. But now I want to select multiple labels as in Excel: Select multiple cells by pressing the mouse for a short time. Not having to click on a label and then on the next and the next and the next, etc ... (it's very slow).

I have thought that it is a combination of a MouseEntered and a MouseClicked but I do not know how or do not know if there is an easier way. Here is my code for selecting labels one by one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = new Label();
            matrix[i][j].setAccessibleHelp(i+","+j);
            matrix[i][j].getStyleClass().add("classic-label");
            matrix[i][j].setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+colorDeath+";");
            matrix[i][j].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    String[] coords = ((Label)event.getSource()).getAccessibleHelp().split(",");
                    //Function that defines the color. I have no problem in this part
                    int x = defineColor(coords);
                    ((Label)event.getSource()).setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+((x == 1) ? colorLife : colorDeath)+";");
                }
            });

            gridPaneMatrix.add(matrix[i][j], i, j);

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement "full press-drag-release gestures", as described in the [`MouseEvent` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html).

Here is a quick demo (though the update of the labels' state is not very efficient, you could probably optimize this with a bit of work).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragToSelect extends Application {

    private class Location { int x; int y ;}

    private PseudoClass selectedClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label[][] matrix = new Label[40][40];
        boolean[][] selected = new boolean[40][40];

        GridPane gridPaneMatrix = new GridPane();

        Location dragAnchor = new Location();



        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

                Location loc = new Location();
                loc.x = i ;
                loc.y = j ;

                matrix[i][j] = new Label();
                matrix[i][j].setAccessibleHelp(i+","+j);
                matrix[i][j].getStyleClass().add("classic-label");
                matrix[i][j].setOnMousePressed(event -> {
                    dragAnchor.x = loc.x ;
                    dragAnchor.y = loc.y ;
                    selected[loc.x][loc.y] = ! selected[loc.x][loc.y];
                    matrix[loc.x][loc.y].pseudoClassStateChanged(selectedClass, selected[loc.x][loc.y]);
                });

                matrix[i][j].setOnDragDetected(e -> {
                    dragAnchor.x = loc.x ;
                    dragAnchor.y = loc.y ;
                    updateState(selected, matrix, dragAnchor, loc);
                    matrix[loc.x][loc.y].startFullDrag();
                });

                matrix[i][j].setOnMouseDragEntered(e -> {
                    System.out.printf("Dragged [%d, %d]%n", loc.x, loc.y);
                    updateState(selected, matrix, dragAnchor, loc);
                });

                gridPaneMatrix.add(matrix[i][j], i, j);

            }

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPaneMatrix);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateState(boolean[][] selected, Label[][] matrix, Location anchor, Location target) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < selected.length ; x++) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < selected[x].length; y++) {
                selected[x][y] = x >= Math.min(anchor.x, target.x)
                        && x <= Math.max(anchor.x, target.x)
                        && y >= Math.min(anchor.y, target.y)
                        && y <= Math.max(anchor.y, target.y) ;
                matrix[x][y].pseudoClassStateChanged(selectedClass, selected[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

style.css:

```css
.classic-label {
    -fx-pref-width: 10 ;
    -fx-pref-height: 15 ;
    -fx-background: black ;
    -fx-background-color: orange, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 0 ;
}
.classic-label:selected {
    -fx-background: limegreen ;
}
```